# Flatten the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to flatten a dataframe in pandas. This is basically by duplicating the column_names with prefix/suffix of occurence/order of the column and the number of extra columns created should be based on the number of rows.

For example:

`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'A': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'B': [50, 60, 70, 80],
    'C': [90, 100, 110, 120]
})

print(df)

#    id   A   B    C
# 0   1  10  50   90
# 1   2  20  60  100
# 2   3  30  70  110
# 3   4  40  80  120



#I want something like the following.

print(result_df)

#    id1  A1   B1   C1  id2  A2   B2   C2  id3  A3   B3   C3  id4  A4   B4   C4
# 0    1  10   50   90    2  20   60  100    3  30   70  110    4  40   80  120
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'A': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'B': [50, 60, 70, 80],
    'C': [90, 100, 110, 120]
})

df_out = df.unstack().to_frame().T.sort_index(level=0)
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j+1}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   id1  id2  id3  id4  A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4  C1   C2   C3   C4
0    1    2    3    4  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.unstack().to_frame().T
```

> ```
>   id            A               B               C
>    0  1  2  3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0    1    2    3
> 0  1  2  3  4  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120
> ```

The `.unstack()` method returns a series, then `.to_frame()` convers it to a dataframe with one column, and finally the `.T` transposes this colomn to a row.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think you posted another solution before that seemed to do what I am looking for.
Still I am trying to make the columns as id1 id2 id3 A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @ScottBoston does the job, with a few modifications:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'A': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'B': [50, 60, 70, 80],
    'C': [90, 100, 110, 120],
})

def key_fn(keys):
    """Modify `id` key to ensure the top of the list"""
    try:
        keys = keys.str.replace("^id$", " id", regex=True)
    except AttributeError:
        # Ignore if regex doesn't suits, this occurs at level 1
        pass
    return keys

df_out = df.unstack().to_frame().sort_index(level=[1, 0], key=key_fn).T
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j+1}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out)
```

### Output:

```
id1  A1  B1  C1  id2  A2  B2   C2  id3  A3  B3   C3  id4  A4  B4   C4
  1  10  50  90    2  20  60  100    3  30  70  110    4  40  80  120
```

### Notes:

- `sort_index()` sorts the index by default, but after transposing by `.T` the index lies in `axis=1`. One workaround is to transpose after sorting, as I did here.
- The `level` has to be specified by sorting DataFrame first by level 1 (row=(0, 1, 2, 3)), then by level 0 (columns=(id, A, B, C)) => `level=[1, 0]`.
- To ensure *id* is listed first, a key adapter `key_fn` prepends a space for column *id*.